# FullCalendar - is it possible to change the position of the end time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

[image]

Comment: Yes you have to do some style modification. Can you post the way it is styled right now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well looking at the code, I couldn't find a very simple way to do this. The reason is, when you add the end time it is added to the start time span, so here is the solution I came up with:

```
$('#cal').fullCalendar({
    'events': test,
    'timeFormat': 'H:mm - {H:mm}'
});

$('.fc-event-time').each(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var time = $(this).text();
    var start = time.split(' - ')[0];
    var finish = time.split(' - ')[1];
    obj.text(start);
    parent.append('<span class="fc-event-time" style="float: right;">' + finish + '</span>');
});
```

[**See it working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/j9TW7/1)

- To start with, add the `'timeFormat'` to the calendar *(I'll assume you already have it to be displaying the finish time)*, give the times a separator `-` *(this will allow splitting of the two times)*

  - ***Note** any time inside the `{}` will be the finish time.*
- Next get jQuery to loop through each element with the class `fc-event-time` *(which is added to the time by fullCalendar)*.
- Now we need to get hold of the parent of the time so we can add an element to it later.
- Next get the time and separate on `-` *(space dash space)*
- Now set the original holder that had both start and finish so it is just the start.
- Now add another span element to the parent, which is the header of the event, but float it to the right and add the finish time.

---

As per [**justkt**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213758/justkt)'s comments, it made me think, the method posted above would only run on page load, so when you changed the view, it wouldn't run again. 
To solve that, add a callback when the events are rendered:

```
$('#cal').fullCalendar({
    'events': test,
    'eventRender' : renderEvents,
    'timeFormat': 'H:mm - {H:mm}',
});

function renderEvents(){
    $('.fc-event-time').each(function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        if (!obj.hasClass('finish-moved')) {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            var time = $(this).text();
            var start = time.split(' - ')[0];
            var finish = time.split(' - ')[1];
            obj.text(start);
            parent.append('<span class="fc-event-time finish-moved" style="float: right;">' + finish + '</span>');
            obj.addClass('finish-moved');
        }
    });
}
```

[**See it working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/j9TW7/4/)

This needed a little more logic adding to it, event render appears to be called for each event, so when the finish time span is added, the next time the loop runs it would try to split finish time, so stop that add a class `finish-moved` so that it isn't affected again.

---

Another update as per [**justkt**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213758/justkt)'s comments again:

When the callback is called it will pass the object it is affecting, so you can 'operate' on just that, instead of running multiple loops:

```
$('#cal').fullCalendar({
    'events': test,
    'eventRender': renderEvents,
    'timeFormat': 'H:mm - {H:mm}',
});

function renderEvents(e, a) {
    var startObj = $(a).find('.fc-event-time');
    var time = $(startObj).text().split(' - ');
    $(startObj).text(time[0]);
    $(a).find('.fc-event-inner').append('<span class="fc-event-time" style="float: right;">' + time[1] + '</span>');
}
```

[**See it working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/j9TW7/6/)

It is a very similar principal, just just operates on the event which has called the callback so should be less resource hungry.

Comment: You could convert that to an eventRender hook that changes the style on render, perhaps.

Comment: @justkt - I twigged on the fact this would work on page load, but not on view changes, so was just looking for the correct callback to hook onto and spotted your comment cheers! I have added to the answer above!

Comment: @Scoobler - looks good.  Personally I'd hook into [eventRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) so that it would happen for only the newly rendered event and scope it on the element argument provided, but what you have looks to work.

Comment: @justkt - I have updated again so it will affect just the event that called the callback - cheers again for the pointer!

Comment: Thanks alot! I will test it when I get back to work on monday :)

Comment: No problem cvack, I would recommend the last update to the answer, it will be the least resource hungry compared to the other versions, I just thought I'd leave them in incase it helps someone else in the future with a slightly different question maybe.